# Time-complexity of mergesort with alternative merge-function

Tags: java, time-complexity, big-o, mergesort

I currently have this code:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File(args[0]));
    int amount = sc.nextInt();
    int[] array = new int[amount];

    for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
        array[i] = sc.nextInt();
    }

    System.out.println("FINAL ANSWER " + find(array, 0, array.length - 1));
}


static int find(int arr[], int l, int r) {
    int answer = 0;
    if (l < r) {
        int m = (l + r) / 2;

        int a = find(arr, l, m);
        int b = find(arr, m + 1, r);

        answer = a + b + answer(arr, l, m, r);
    }
    return answer;
}


static int answer(int arr[], int l, int m, int r) {
    int ans = 0;
    for (int i = m; i < r; i++) {
        for (int j = l; j < m + 1; j++) {

            if (arr[i + 1] > arr[j]) {
                ans++;

            }
        }
    }

    return ans;
}
```

I know mergesort has a time-complexity of *O(nlog(n))*, however I've replaced the merge-function by a function with two for-loops. So is it now *O(n^2)* since `l`, `m` and `r` depend on *n*?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: What is the time complexity

Answer (score 0):

The function `answer` has a complexity of `O( (r-m) * (m+1-l) )`. The outer for-loop goes from `m` to `r`, thus `r-m` iterations. The inner for-loop goes from `l` to `m+1`, so `m+1-l` iterations.

Given the worst case `l=0`,`r=n` and `m=n/2`, the function can be approximated to `O(n^2)`.

However you need to add the runtime of the function `find`. So the overall time complexity will be:

- `O(n^2 * log(n))`.